# How to exclude a file to don't build by Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and GIT. Actually the structure of my application is:

Code is sit in GIT Contains two branches(`Dev` and `Prod`) and cloned to Visual Studio. So, when i make modifications i'll push to `dev` and `prod` branches from Visual Studio. Here all files and folders will sync to server automatically using `Jenkins`.

My requirement is, i don't want one .dll file to be sync to Server automatically. How can i stop that? Is it from GIT side or from Jenkins side.

Comment: What is meant by sync to server automatically using Jenkins? What commands are you running for the sync to happen? If it is the `rsync` command, you can simply ignore the file using the `exclude` flag as in `rsync -razv --exclude="path/to/dll" . user@server:/target/path/`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your problem here. You mean that the files you "build locally" are pushed to the repository ? If it's the case you need to add them to your .gitignore. My answer seems trivial but I refer to "I'm new to Jenkins and GIT".

Not that if you have already pushed then your git repository will have them stored anyway and you would need some rebase to cleanup.

**so:**

1) you should consider locally deleting the files you don't want in the git repo, then create a new commit

2) create/edit the .gitignore file in order to not add them again and create another commit
--> one commit to cleanup, then one to add the files to gitignore

**Side note**:
- you should always use the **git status** to be aware of what you are adding to the repository. Often password and unwanted content hit the repo that way.

Comment: Yes, when i commit and push my changes will go to git and sync to server using jenkins.

Comment: If i give path of the file in .gitignore, it won't sync to GIT right! If yes, i want them to keep in GIT but not sync to server.

Comment: jenkins usually do a git clone+checkout of your git. So I'm not sure to understand your need here. You want some files present in your local and git repo but not in jenkins ?